# Limiting jTextArea text length with backspace not working correctly

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, limit, jtextarea

So I have created a text limiting function in my desktop app, but I can't seem to get it to stop backspacing at exactly the right position.

What the limit does, is it runs the function *CheckSize()* as a new thread while the user hasn't clicked the Submit button. *CheckSize()* looks at the content of a jTextArea, and it has length conditions. Once the overflow-length (256 characters) has been met, *enforceLimit()* is called to put the caret at the end of the textarea and backspace one character.

The problem now, is that during a test, it would meet the overflow-length condition and backspace one, two or even three characters at random, never just until the text length is 256. In other words, if there is 257 characters, the app chooses if it wants to backspace until 256, or 255 or 254. Simply put, it doesn't listen to the instructions given - or I'm not making my instructions clear enough..?

In the screenshot below, you'll see that the user creates a message, and the message content (`txtMessage`) has a limit of 256 characters (`lblChar`). The moment the user has typed up to the maximum amount of characters, the app shows that the word count is too high and then *supposedly* backspaces the character typed to shorten the message content to only 256 characters.

I found the idea of using a robot on another SO example.

[image: Screenshot of Desktop App]

**Code:**

```
import com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class AddBulletin extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public AddBulletin() {
        WebLookAndFeel.install();
        initComponents();
        CheckSize();
    }

    private void CheckSize() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                do {
                    int txtLen = txtMessage.getText().length();

                    lblChar.setText(Integer.toString(txtLen));
                    if (txtLen > (256 - (256 * 0.1)) && txtLen <= 256) {
                        lblChar.setForeground(Color.orange);
                    } else if (txtLen > 256) {
                        lblChar.setForeground(Color.red);
                        enforceLimit();
                    } else {
                        lblChar.setForeground(Color.green);
                    }
                } while (!btnSubmit.isSelected());
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    private void enforceLimit() {
        try {
            txtMessage.setCaretPosition(txtMessage.getText().length());
            System.out.println("Position: " + txtMessage.getCaretPosition());
            Robot r = new Robot();
            int bsp = KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE;
            r.keyPress(bsp);
            r.keyRelease(bsp);
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        txtTitle = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txtMessage = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblChar = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnClear = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnSubmit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnCancel = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cboType = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 255));

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 255));

        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel2.setText("Title:");

        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel3.setText("Message:");

        txtMessage.setColumns(20);
        txtMessage.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        txtMessage.setLineWrap(true);
        txtMessage.setRows(5);
        txtMessage.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txtMessageKeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txtMessage);

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel4.setText("/ 256");

        lblChar.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        lblChar.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblChar.setText("0");

        jLabel6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel6.setText("Author:");

        jTextField2.setEditable(false);

        btnClear.setText("Clear");
        btnClear.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnClearActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnSubmit.setText("Submit");

        btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnCancelActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel7.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel7.setText("Type:");

        cboType.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Information", "Announcement" }));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGap(8, 8, 8)))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 297, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(txtTitle)))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(btnClear, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                                .addComponent(btnSubmit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 101, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                                .addComponent(btnCancel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(246, 246, 246)
                                        .addComponent(lblChar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel4))
                                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                            .addComponent(cboType, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, 0, 297, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))))))))
                .addGap(23, 23, 23))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 21, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 96, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(lblChar)))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                    .addComponent(cboType, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(btnClear)
                        .addComponent(btnCancel))
                    .addComponent(btnSubmit))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 255));

        jLabel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 255));
        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("Create Message");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
        );

        jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 255));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jSeparator1)
                .addGap(0, 0, 0))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, 0)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, 0)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnCancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        this.dispose();
    }                                         

    private void btnClearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        txtMessage.setText("");
        txtTitle.setText("");
    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddBulletin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddBulletin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddBulletin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddBulletin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new AddBulletin().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnCancel;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnClear;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnSubmit;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox cboType;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblChar;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea txtMessage;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtTitle;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: What is this all about? What is the purpose of the code, the behavior that you want the user to experience? Also,  consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Basically, it shows the user how much characters they have typed and shows them that the limit has been reached, and that the extra characters have been removed, without having to use a message dialog. Will update original question.

Comment: I wonder if you want to use a DocumentFilter for this purpose. I have no idea why you're using a Robot object since JTextComponents have caret functionality. Also, please don't forget that for best results, consider creating and posting your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) program.

Comment: Updated to the best of my abilities... I'll look into caret functionality.

Comment: Still no minimal compilable runnable program. Also you're doing continuous polling, something that is completely unnecessary, and again can be avoided with a simple DocumentFilter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My minimal runnable example. Again, use a DocumentFilter:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class EnforceSizeTest extends JPanel {
   private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 256;
   private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(15, 20);

   public EnforceSizeTest() {
      textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
      textArea.setLineWrap(true);
      ((PlainDocument) textArea.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new MyDocumentFilter(MAX_LENGTH));

      add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
   }

   private class MyDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {
      private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 256;
      private int maxLength;

      public MyDocumentFilter(int maxLength) {
         this.maxLength = maxLength;
      }

      @Override
      public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string,
            AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
         Document doc = fb.getDocument();
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
         sb.insert(offset, string);
         if (sb.length() > maxLength) {
            return;
         }
         super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
      }

      @Override
      public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
            AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
         Document doc = fb.getDocument();
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
         sb.replace(offset, offset + length, text);
         if (sb.length() > MAX_LENGTH) {
            return;
         }
         super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      EnforceSizeTest mainPanel = new EnforceSizeTest();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("EnforceSizeTest");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Now I understand the functionality of a DocumentFilter! (and how to create a mcve :D) I must say, I never knew such a tool existed - I'm a self Java learner, learning by example.

Comment: @JohanBrink `I'm a self Java learner, learning by example` - I always point people to the Swing tutorial which has a section on [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) that does exactly this. Not only does the example work but it has a brief explanation about the code. Also, you now have a reference to the Swing tutorial that contains valuable information on many topics all with working examples, so I would suggest you take a look.